What is the complete idyllic medieval life?
Holidays half the time, natural air and hunting, better sex, bigger houses, religious cultures that loved parties and festivals, less taxes, bosses who were mostly absent- I've heard a lot of loose mythology about how medieval life was basically a utopia of superior living that our modern industrialized society will never meet.
Has anyone or could anyone do a good summary of this perspective? I am not interested in real history, and real history made searching this up hard. I am interested in the utopian perspective that medieval life was basically better in every way than modern life so I can use it to write a story.
A good answer will give a fairly comprehensive and complete picture of this perspective so I can make a world based off it. A poor answer will insist on historical accuracy- I am not writing a history story.

I do not understand what kind of answer is expected. If historical reality is irrelevant, then what is relevant? Sure, if historical reality is irrelevant, then medieval life was paradise on Earth. Think of it's very name -- medieval life, that is, living all of one's life among Eves! Nobody was forced to vaccinate themselves; all that was necessary for life was found in one's own village; there were no traffic jams, because there was no traffic; one did not have to pay money for anything, as there was no money; no need to worry about misinformation, as there was no information at all.

We do have a utopia tag, so fictional societies which there's a utopia are presumably on topic. It's like asking what Plato's republic was like, except the republic's easy to google. Presumably someone online can summarize why they feel medieval society was so great. https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/2b8ovr/ive_seen_it_argued_that_medieval_peasants/ this is an example of the sort of perspective I've seen and found when googling it.

Questions about a mythical utopia can only get opinions, not answers.

There is a utopia tag, so there are answers on it. Most questions here involve fictional things, not real things.

As for all questions, the [tag:utopia] tag's purpose is to identify the intent of a question about a specific problem. Stack Exchange is not a free research service and questions are expected to be focused on a single problem (e.g., in a utopic late-period English medieval society, what would be the best state of food transportation?) Frankly, after reading the nearly useless tag wiki, I could be convinced to burn the tag. As for hunting for a utopic medieval society (which isn't the intent of the tag per its wiki), legitimate answers would be things like ... (*Continued*)

... plentiful game that never depletes, fertile soil with steady rain and bright sunshine every year, no desire for banditry or personal gain that would lead to crime, clean water that didn't necessitate alcohol, no disease and benign government, and an entirely equitable trade system (whatever that means) so that chickens and bread are worth the tools needed to produce them - and every man is handsome, every woman beautiful, every child pleasant, and every serf can become a knight. If that didn't entirely answer your question, then you need to define what "utopia" means in a medieval context.

I think the idyllic depiction of the medieval dream life is summarized in the myth of Cockaigne:

Cockaigne or Cockayne (/kɒˈkeɪn/) is a land of plenty in medieval myth, an imaginary place of luxury and ease, comfort and pleasure, opposite to the harshness of medieval peasant life. In poems like The Land of Cockaigne, it is a land of contraries, where all the restrictions of society are defied (abbots beaten by their monks), sexual liberty is open (nuns flipped over to show their bottoms), and food is plentiful (skies that rain cheese). Cockaigne appeared frequently in Goliard verse. It represented both wish fulfillment and resentment at scarcity and Christian asceticism.


Cockaigne was a "medieval peasant’s dream, offering relief from backbreaking labor and the daily struggle for meager food."


Like Atlantis and El Dorado, the land of Cockaigne was a utopia. It was a fictional place where, in a parody of paradise, idleness and gluttony were the principal occupations. In Specimens of Early English Poets (1790), George Ellis printed a 13th-century French poem called "The Land of Cockaigne" where "the houses were made of barley sugar and cakes, the streets were paved with pastry, and the shops supplied goods for nothing".
According to Herman Pleij, Dreaming of Cockaigne: Medieval Fantasies of the Perfect Life (2003):
roasted pigs wander about with knives in their backs to make carving easy, where grilled geese fly directly into one's mouth, where cooked fish jump out of the water and land at one's feet. The weather is always mild, the wine flows freely, sex is readily available, and all people enjoy eternal youth.

